# Insert into two diffrent tables a foregin key from third table in same form submit

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

I have three tables: users, courses and grads.

- users table (id, username, pass, course_id).
- courses table (id, coursename, description).
- grads table (user_id, course_id, grade).

I have a form to add a new user which include a dropdown list which shows the available courses with the value "id" from courses table.

When a course been added to the database the dropdown list will be updated.

Now, what I try to do is:

When I use the form to add new user and I choose the course from the dropdown list, I want the same value for the course being choosen sent to the grades table (course_id) and the (user_id) which will be added with the same submit action.

I use Wrapper classes php and PDO, just explain with normal PDO.

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/header.php';
include 'includes/headeradmin.php';



if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {   ### Security check

   $validate = new Validate();
   $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(

    'email' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'min'      => 2,
        'max'      => 20,
        'unique'   => 'users'
    ),

    'password' => array(
        'required'  => true,
        'min'       => 6
    ),

    'password_again' => array(
        'required'  => true,
        'matches'   => 'password'
    ),

    'fullname' => array(
        'required'  => true,
        'min'       => 2,
        'max'       => 20
    ),

    'group_id' => array(

        'min'       => 1,
        'max'       => 20
    ),

    'class_id' => array(

        'min'       => 1,
        'max'       => 20
    ),

    'course_id' => array(

        'min'       => 1,
        'max'       => 20
    )

));



if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();
            $salt = Hash::salt(32);

            try {

            $user->create(array(
                'email' => Input::get('email'),
                'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                'fullname' => Input::get('fullname'),
                'address'  => Input::get('address'),
                'telnumber'=> Input::get('telnumber'),
                'salt'     => $salt,
                'group_id' => Input::get('group_id'),
                'class_id' => Input::get('class_id'),
                'course_id'=> Input::get('course_id'),

                ));


                    echo "En ny användaren Har skapat";
                #Session::flash('home', 'you are registerd successfully');
                #Redirect::to('index.php');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die ($e->getMessage());
            }

        #Session::flash('success', 'You registered successfully');
        #header('Location: index.php');
   } else {
      foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
        echo $error,'<br>';

      }
    }
}  
}

?>



<form  id ="regform" action="" method="post">
    <div id="register">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td style="width:130px; text-align: right"><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
        <td style="width: 200px"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('email')); ?>" autocomplete="off" width="200px"></td>

    </tr>

   <tr>
        <td style="width:130px; text-align: right"><label for="password">Password:</label>
        <td style="width: 200px"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" width="200px"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="width:130px; text-align: right"><label for="password_again">Re Enter your password:</label></td>
        <td style="width: 200px"><input type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again" width="200px"></td>
    </tr>

   <tr>
        <td style="width:130px; text-align: right"><label for="fullname">Full Name:</label></td>
        <td style="width: 200px"><input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullnmae" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('fullname')); ?>" autocomplete="off" width="200px"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="width:130px; text-align: right"><label for="address">Address:</label></td>
        <td style="width: 200px"><input type="text" name="address" id="address" width="200px"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="width:130px; text-align: right"><label for="telnumber">Tel. Number:
        </label></td>
        <td style="width: 200px"><input type="text" name="telnumber" id="telnumber" width="200px"></td>
    </tr>

   <tr>
        <td style="width:130px; text-align: right"><label for="group_id">Permission:</label></td>
        <td style="width: 200px; text-align: center"><select name="group_id" width="200px">
        <option value="0">Select a permission</option>
        <option value="1">Student</option>
        <option value="2">Admin</option>
        <option value="3">Teacher</option>
        </select></td>
 </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="width:130px; text-align: right"><label for="class_id">Class:</label></td>
        <td style="width: 200px; text-align: center"><select name="class_id" width="200px">
        <option value="0">Select a Class</option>
        <?php 
            $class = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM classes");
                foreach ($class->results() as $class) {
        echo '<option value="'. $class->id .'">' . $class->classname . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
        </select></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="width:130px; text-align: right"><label for="course_id">Course:</label></td>
        <td style="width: 200px; text-align: center"><select name="course_id" width="200px">
        <option value="0">Select a Course</option>

        <?php 
            $course = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM courses");
                foreach ($course->results() as $course) {
        echo '<option value="'. $course->id .'">' . $course->coursename . '</option>';
        }
        ?>

        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:130px; text-align: right"></td>
    <td style="width: 200px"><input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td style="width:130px; text-align: right"></td>
        <td style="width: 200px; text-align: center"> <input type="submit"  value="Register"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I added this code after $user->create so its look like that

```
$user->create(array(
                'email' => Input::get('email'),
                'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                'fullname' => Input::get('fullname'),
                'address'  => Input::get('address'),
                'telnumber'=> Input::get('telnumber'),
                'salt'     => $salt,
                'group_id' => Input::get('group_id'),
                'class_id' => Input::get('class_id'),
                'course_id'=> Input::get('course_id'),

                ));

                $grad = DB::getInstance()->insert('grads', array(
                        'user_id' => Input::get(LAST_INSERT_ID()),
                        'course_id' => Input::get('course_id'),
                    ));
```

but i got this error :
Fatal error: Call to undefined function LAST_INSERT_ID() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Jensenonline1\register.php on line 77

Comment: Please show your code and explain what's wrong with it, so we can help you fix it.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the MySQL `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function. This contains the auto_increment ID that was assigned to the row that was just inserted, and you can use it when inserting into the tables with the foreign key.

Comment: thanx,,,i wrapped all the things in classes,,, so it will be hard  to explaine...but it will help if you explaind more passed on the example i wrote.....  last_insert_id for the user_id that be added last,,,,,,,,what about the course_id ????

Comment: Why do you have a `course_id` column in the `grads` table? If it's the same as the `course_id` in `users`, you don't need to repeat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function in MySQL to get the ID that was assigned to the user that was just created. Create the new user with a query like this:

```
$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, pass, course_id) 
                        VALUES (:username, :pass, :course_id)");
$stmt1->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username'],
                      ':pass' => $_POST['password'],
                      ':course_id' => $_POST['course_id']));
```

Then to add to `grades`, use:

```
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO grades (user_id, course_id)
                        VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), :course_id)");
$stmt2->execute(array(':course_id' => $_POST['course_id']));
```

Since you use the same `$_POST['course_id']` when executing both queries, the same value will be put in both tables.

Comment: i need the course_id in grads table for login permissions. The grade table will allow teacher to set a grade for a student and when the student show his courses will see the grades which he got for every course.                           So when i write the last insert id with the second insert command,, will known that i want the course_id for the same user too???

Comment: When you do the inserts, you'll use the same `$_POST['course_id']` in both calls.

Comment: Why can't you use a `JOIN` to get the course ID for login permissions, instead of duplicating it? But if a student can be in multiple courses, why is there a `course_id` column in the `users` table? Does the same student have multple entries in the `users` table?

Comment: i will add the code for the register file,,,that you have a bitter pic.    how to add the full code here

Comment: i'm a new in php and this is a school project ...new beginner....will add the database diagrame which after i looked att it now i figuer out that its wrong....please help....NO TIME

Comment: Forget about all that. Just use the answer I gave you.

Comment: I've added some real PDO code to my answer, I hope that makes it more understandable.

Comment: did you saw how i grab the data from the form???   how i can pass the LAST_INSERT_ID()  in the same way????

Comment: You don't need to pass it at all. It's internal to MySQL.

Comment: i'm sorry,,,, can you explain more passed of my code???   where to excute the insert code for grades???  after the create user or where??

Comment: You insert into grades right after you insert into users.

Comment: I guess they'll both be inside `User::create()`.

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is a MySQL function, not a PHP function. It doesn't come from the form, so you can't use it with `Input::get()`. It has to be in the actual SQL, like in my answer. Or you can use the PDO method `$DB::getInstance->lastInsertId()`.

Comment: You said I should give an answer with normal PDO, and you would figure out how to translate it to your wrapper class.